# How to reset Python environment to its initial empty state?

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, package, reset

This question is similar to [How do I detect and remove Python packages installed via `pip`?](https://askubuntu.com/q/173323/448153) on AskUbuntu, but I am looking for a simpler and more basic solution than the ones proposed for that question.  I would also like to understand the structure of Python environment and how it is spread over the system.

I am mostly interested in solutions for Ubuntu Linux and similar systems, but I imagine that solutions for Mac OS or maybe even for Windows should not be very different.

I would like to reset my Python environment to the initial empty state without reinstalling my OS (Ubuntu). However, I do not want to touch any parts of the environment installed with the OS package manager (`apt`). Well, I have not installed any Python packages with `apt` anyway.  In practice, this means I want to remove and purge all packages installed with `pip` and all the artefacts they might have left on the system.

It looks like an appropriate solution might be the one mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/173323/448153#comment1259699_259747):

```bash
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.5
```

Will this really remove everything?  What about executable scripts (or binaries) installed as parts of Python packages?

Suppose now that I didn't use `pip` with `sudo` and installed all my Python packages with `pip install --user`.  What would be the way to remove them completely in this case?

I did not use `virtualenv`.

---

These were my main general questions, but they come from a more specific one.  I have encountered an error when using `matplotlib`, and from the error messages it seems like Python is complaining about missing `matplotlib.externals` module.  Indeed:

```python
import matplotlib.externals
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'
```

There was a [similar issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5633/) reported "against" `matplotlib` (just kidding), which was apparently caused my multiple conflicting versions of `matplotlib`.  However, in my case, even if I do `rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.5` and reinstall `matplotlib`, the error is reproduced.  I did not use Anaconda.

Comment: How deep would you like to go? I'm asking because in theory, an installation script can install anything, anywhere. Specifically, just removing `.../python3.5` is not enough. Packages might have been installed somewhere in the context of the user, not the system and data files might have been deployed elsewhere. I would uninstall (loopishly) all installed packages using pip and then use apt to remove python. Is that deep enough for your needs?

Comment: I do not want to remove python. In particular because other `apt` packages depend on it and the operation gets a bit nontrivial (a reinstall of the OS starts looking like a reasonable alternative).  As i said, i do not want to remove anything installed by `apt`, i only want to remove things installed through Pyrthon infrastructure (`pip`, etc.).  Of course we should assume that the installed packages behaved "nicely", otherwise my question would not make sense.

Comment: Well then, since the installation of python packages can practically do anything, the best way would be to just pip uninstall them by looping through the `pip freeze` output. There's no "state" kept for a python installation so you can't follow up on what each package does (which is obviously a problem), but anything installed via data files or package data will be removed.

Comment: Would also highly recommend you start using virtualenv, thus leaving your system Python alone and allowing you to do whatever you want in virtualenv. Very flexible and avoids issues like this where you're limited by the fact that the OS depends on your "everyday" Python.

Comment: @Alexey How did that come along for you?

Comment: I already tried before uninstalling all packages output by `freeze`, but there were some errors, some failed to uninstall.

Comment: @FilipKilibarda, would `virtualenv` be of any help if even removing `/usr/local/lib/python3.5` does not help?

Comment: @Alexey if all you want is to get `matplotlib` running, then you should get `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` (I think via `pip` would be easiest). Using these tools, you can make a barebones copy of your system Python stored in some dir of your choice. After stepping into the virtual environment, you can install `matplotlib` and whatever else in a completely isolated environment. You delete the `virtualenv` by simply deleting the dir. if that doesn't work then your problem becomes more interesting - and maybe consider posting another question!

Comment: Does this help at all? https://askubuntu.com/questions/675142/restore-python-installation-to-default-plus-apt-package-dependencies